# How can i import csv files as variables into a python code?

Tags: python, csv, finance

I have never used python before but need to use it to get acces to data for my bachelor thesis. The code is already written but i need to import data in order to get the output i need(the code is for the calculation of model-free implied volatility) The source of this code is: https://www.vilkov.net/codedata.html.

But i cannot figure out how i could import my data files in order to let the program run.

Any help would be appreciated.

Greatings Bram

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Stackoverflow is to help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.